# Laravel 5.3 - Sometimes views get broken and show script

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I think it's a bit hard to explain with words so I put some screenshots. Sometimes the view get broken after several refresh like 2 out of 5 tries. It always break on **content right div** until **the end of the page**.

> Not Break: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpRJU.png
>
> Break After Several Refresh: https://i.stack.imgur.com/swbQ1.png

I think the problem can be at my master blade layout or the page.

This is the **Master Blade Layout**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en">

    <head>

        @include('partial._head')

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="container main-container">
            
            <div class="row row-bg">
                
                @include('partial._nav')
                
            </div>
            
            <div class="row row-bg">
                
                @include('partial._title')


                
            </div>
            
            <div class="row row-bg">
                
                <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 content-container">

                    <div class="text-center text-uppercase content-title"> 

                        @yield('content-title') 
                        @yield('session')

                    </div>
                    
                    <hr>
                    
                    <div class="content">
                    
                        @yield('content')
                        
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row row-bg pb-1">
                
                <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 content-left">
                    
                    @yield('content-left')          

                </div>

                <div class="col-md-5 content-right">
                    
                    @yield('content-right')          

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        @include('partial._footer')

        @include('partial._script')
        
    </body>

</html>
```

This is the **Page code**

```
@extends('main')

@section('title', 'Registrasi Akun')

@section('content-title')

    Registrasi Akun

@stop

@section('content')

    <div class="col-sm-12">
        
        {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'route' => 'register', 'class' => 'form-horizontal' ]) !!}
            
            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('username') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                {!! Form::label('username', 'Username', ['class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label']) !!}
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    {!! Form::text('username', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 
                                                                 'required' => 'required', 
                                                                 'minlength' => '6', 
                                                                 'maxlength' => '15', 
                                                                 'pattern' => '^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$', 
                                                                 'title' => 'only accept alphanum and dashes'
                                                                ]) !!}
                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('username') }}</small>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                {!! Form::label('password', 'Password', ['class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label']) !!}
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    {!! Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control', 
                                                               'required' => 'required', 
                                                               'minlength' => '8', 
                                                               'maxlength' => '16'
                                                               ]) !!}
                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('password') }}</small>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                {!! Form::label('password_confirmation', 'Password Again', ['class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label']) !!}
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    {!! Form::password('password_confirmation', ['class' => 'form-control',
                                                                            'required' => 'required'
                                                                        ]) !!}
                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</small>
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr>

            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('fullname') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                {!! Form::label('fullname', 'Nama Lengkap', ['class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label']) !!}
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    {!! Form::text('fullname', null, ['class' => 'form-control',
                                                                 'required' => 'required',
                                                                 'pattern' => '^[a-zA-Z ]*$',
                                                                 'title' => 'only accept  alphabet and spaces'
                                                                 ]) !!}
                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('fullname') }}</small>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                {!! Form::label('email', 'Email', ['class' =>'col-sm-3 control-label']) !!}
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    {!! Form::email('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control',
                                                               'required' => 'required',
                                                               'placeholder' => 'eg: foo@bar.com'
                                                               ]) !!}
                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</small>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('phone_number') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                {!! Form::label('phone_number', 'No. Telepon', ['class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label']) !!}
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    {!! Form::text('phone_number', null, ['class' => 'form-control',
                                                                     'required' => 'required', 
                                                                     'pattern' => '^[0-9]*$', 
                                                                     'title' => 'input number only eg: 081222333444'
                                                                     ]) !!}
                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('phone_number') }}</small>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('gender') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                {!! Form::label('gender', 'Input label', ['class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label']) !!}
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    {!! Form::select('gender', [null => 'Choose...', 'male' => 'Pria', 'female' => 'Wanita'], null, ['id' => 'gender', 'class' => 'form-control',
                                                                                                                                                  'required' => 'required'
                                                                                                                                                  ]) !!}
                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('gender') }}</small>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('address') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                {!! Form::label('address', 'Input', ['class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label']) !!}
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    {!! Form::textarea('address', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 
                                                                    'required' => 'required', 
                                                                    'minlength' => '50'
                                                                    ]) !!}
                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('address') }}</small>
                </div>
            </div>
            

    </div>

@stop

@section('content-left')
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="checkbox{{ $errors->has('setuju') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label for="setuju" class="text-white">
                        {!! Form::checkbox('setuju', '1', 0, ['id' => 'setuju', 'required' => 'required']) !!}
                        Saya telah membaca dan menerima <br> <a class="disini" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#syarat" href="#">Syarat dan Peraturan</a> dari Garena.
                    </label>
                </div>
                <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('setuju') }}</small>
            </div>

            @include('partial._modal')


@stop

@section('content-right')
    
            {!! Form::submit('Register', ['class' => 'btn this-btn btn-garena pull-right']) !!}

        {!! Form::close() !!}

@stop

@section('scripts')

    <script>
        
        var password = document.getElementById("password"),
            confirm_password = document.getElementById("password_confirmation");

        function validatePassword(){
            if(password.value != confirm_password.value) {
                confirm_password.setCustomValidity("Passwords Don't Match");
            } else {
                confirm_password.setCustomValidity('');
            }
        }

        password.onchange = validatePassword;
        confirm_password.onkeyup = validatePassword;

    </script>

@stop
```

Comment: I'd be more interesting in seeing the source code when it breaks as opposed to a picture.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I'm sorry I can't provide the source code because it seems like its fixed but I didn't know how. I tried to refresh the page several times but it doesn't get broken like before.

Answer (score 0):

where is your 'scripts' yield ?
according to this line `@section('scripts')` you should have one.

Comment: its inside `@include('partial._script)`